# C# Regular expression for input values of Textbox

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to validate the text within a textbox using a regular expression.
The text should be a number greater than 0 and less than and equal to 1000.

Comment: You dont want to use range validator??

Comment: want to do by regular expression validator only

Answer (score 3):

`"^[1-9][0-9]*{1,2}$"` is the regex you are looking for.

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(YourTextBox.Text,"^[1-9][0-9]*{1,2}$"))
{
    //Write your logic here 
}
```

Comment: I think less than 1000 means 3 digits max, therefore {1,3} should be {1,2} as you've alreay got the first digit from the [1-9].

Comment: This code return ArgumentException was unhandled:parsing "^[1-9][0-9]*{1,2}$" - Nested quantifier {.

Comment: a **)** is needed at the end of first line

Comment: but i want validate expression

Comment: same here return argument exception

Comment: this regex is not match single number like `5`. and `*` make regex invalid

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
//for  0 < x < 1000
^((?<=[1-9])0|[1-9]){1,3}$
```

explain:

```
(?<=[1-9])0     //look behind to see if there is digits (1-9)
```

test:

```
0   ->  invalid
000 ->  invalid
45  ->  valid
5   ->  valid      'Ashwin Singh' solution can not capture this
101 ->  valid
999 ->  valid
1000    ->  invalid
12345   ->  invalid
10000   ->  invalid
2558    ->  invalid
205 ->  valid
1001    ->  invalid
2000    ->  invalid
```

---

And better way convert to `Decimal` (if you dont use regular expression validator):

```
Decimal dc = Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text);
if( dc > 0 && dc < 1000)
// do some thing
```

Comment: The `((?<=\d)0|[1-9]){1,3}` return true for value greater than 1000

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$|^(1000)
```

I test it in range 0~1000